# Spring-Cloud-Netlix-Eureka - Upgrading Spring Neflix Eureka Client Removes EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration.java . Spring ->boot - 2.7.12 , Cloud-2021x

Tags: java, build.gradle, upgrade, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

[tag:`Working on upgrading gateway project to spring cloud - 2.7.12 and Spring Cloud 2021.0.7 but due to this netflix -spring libraries are upgrading and EurekaRibbonClient Configuration class is removed .
Now Getting Errors :
2024-02-16 14:50:33 [http-nio-8888-exec-8] [] [] ERROR c.s.g.z.f.p.DefaultZuulFallbackProvider - Root cause of internal server error in Zuul Fallback provider -
com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: backuprestore

My own ribbonconfig class

```
package com.netflix.loadbalancer;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import com.netflix.appinfo.EurekaInstanceConfig; import com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClientConfig; import org.slf4j.Logger; import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value; import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean; import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties; import org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.config.LoadBalancerZoneConfig; import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.loadbalancer.EurekaLoadBalancerProperties; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration; import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import com.netflix.client.ClientFactory; import com.netflix.client.config.CommonClientConfigKey; import com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig;

/**

This is the default Ribbon configuration for all Ribbon clients. Routing rules and Load balancer

to be used by Ribbon can be configured.



*/ @Configuration @EnableConfigurationProperties public class GatewayRibbonConfig extends EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatewayRibbonConfig.class);

@Value("${zuul.ribbonRuleClass:#{null}}")
private String ribbonRuleClassName;

@Value("${zuul.ribbonLoadBalancerClass:#{null}}")
private String ribbonLoadBalancerClassName;

/**
 * Ribbon rule to be used for load balancing and filtering servers
 * @param config
 * @return
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@Bean
public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config){
    IRule rule = null;
    String ruleClassName = ribbonRuleClassName;
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(ruleClassName)) {
        ruleClassName = config.get(CommonClientConfigKey.NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName);
    }
    
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(ruleClassName)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName is not specified in the IClientConfig");
    }
    
    Class clazz = null;
    try {
        clazz =  Class.forName(ruleClassName);
        if (clazz.getConstructor(IClientConfig.class) != null) {
            try {
                return (IRule) clazz.getConstructor(IClientConfig.class).newInstance(config);
            }catch (InstantiationException e) {
                logger.warn("Error getting/invoking IClientConfig constructor of {}", ruleClassName, e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                logger.warn("Error getting/invoking IClientConfig constructor of {}", ruleClassName, e);
            }  
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
        // OK for a class to not take an IClientConfig, I
    } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.warn("Error getting/invoking IClientConfig constructor of {}", ruleClassName, e);
    } 
    
    try {
        if (clazz.getConstructor() != null) {
            rule = (IRule) clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
            try {
                Method method = clazz.getMethod("initWithNiwsConfig", IClientConfig.class);
                method.invoke(rule, config);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException igonore) {
                // can be ignored
            } catch( SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                logger.warn("Error invoking initWithNiwsConfig method of {}", ruleClassName, e);
                throw new RuntimeException("Error while initilaizing rule " + ruleClassName,e) ;
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        logger.error("Error getting/invoking no-arg constructor of {}", ruleClassName, e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while initilaizing rule " + ruleClassName,e) ;
    }
    return rule;
}

/*@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public ServerList<?> ribbonServerList(IClientConfig config) {
    return new com.netflix.niws.loadbalancer.DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList(config);
}*/

/**
 * Load balancer to be used by ribbon
 * @param config
 * @param serverList
 * @param serverListFilter
 * @param rule
 * @param ping
 * @param serverListUpdater
 * @return
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 */
 @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
 @Bean
 @ConditionalOnMissingBean
 public ILoadBalancer loadBalancer(IClientConfig config,
                                      ServerList<Server> serverList,
                                      ServerListFilter<Server> serverListFilter,
                                      IRule rule, IPing ping,
                                      ServerListUpdater serverListUpdater) throws ClassNotFoundException {
     
    String loadBalancerClassName = ribbonLoadBalancerClassName;
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(loadBalancerClassName)) {
        loadBalancerClassName = config.get(CommonClientConfigKey.NFLoadBalancerClassName);
    }
    
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(loadBalancerClassName)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("NFLoadBalancerClassName is not specified in the IClientConfig");
    }
    
    Class clazz = Class.forName(loadBalancerClassName);
    try {
        if (clazz.getConstructor(IClientConfig.class,IRule.class,IPing.class,ServerList.class,ServerListFilter.class,ServerListUpdater.class) != null) {
            try {
                return (ILoadBalancer) clazz.getConstructor(IClientConfig.class,IRule.class,IPing.class,ServerList.class,ServerListFilter.class,ServerListUpdater.class).newInstance(config, rule, ping, serverList,
                        serverListFilter, serverListUpdater);
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                logger.warn("Error getting/invoking IClientConfig,IRule, IPing, ServerList,ServerListFilter,ServerListUpdater constructor of {}", loadBalancerClassName, e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                logger.warn("Error getting/invoking IClientConfig,IRule, IPing, ServerList,ServerListFilter,ServerListUpdater constructor of {}", loadBalancerClassName, e);
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
        // OK for a class to not take an IClientConfig, I
    } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) { 
        logger.warn("Error getting/invoking IClientConfig,IRule, IPing, ServerList,ServerListFilter,ServerListUpdater constructor of {}", loadBalancerClassName, e);
    }
    
    ILoadBalancer lb;
    try {
        lb = (ILoadBalancer) ClientFactory.instantiateInstanceWithClientConfig(loadBalancerClassName, config);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return lb;
    
    //return new DynamicServerListLoadBalancer<>(config, rule, ping, serverList,
    //      serverListFilter, serverListUpdater);
 }
}
```

snapshot of dependencies

```
buildscript { ext { springBootVersion = '2.7.12' springfoxSwaggerVersion = '2.9.2' jacocoVersion = '0.8.9' swaggerVersion= '2.4.12' }

dependencyManagement { imports { mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.7' } }
implementation ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:2.2.10.RELEASE")
implementation ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul:2.2.10.RELEASE")
implementation ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:2.2.10.RELEASE")
implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon', version: '2`.2.10.RELEASE'`
```

Trying to upgrade java and gradle